# No conversion path for dtype ('<U1') issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a 2d list (Data_set) that contain a 3d array and a label(0 or 1), I want to make the h5py file with two datasets one for 3d array and the other for the label, this is my code for doing that:
`

```
    data = []
    label = []
    for i in range(len(Data_set)):
        data.append(Data_set[i][0])# 3d array
        label.append(Data_set[i][1])#label
    data = np.array(data)
    label = np.array(label)
    dt = np.dtype('int16')
    with h5py.File(output_path+'dataset.h5', 'w') as hf:
        hf.create_dataset('data',dtype=dt ,data=data, compression='lzf')
        hf.create_dataset('label', dtype=dt, data=label, compression='lzf')
```

`
the content of the 2d list is shown in the image below:
[image]
but when I run the code it gives me an error: see the image below
[image]
please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: When you provide the `data` parameter you don't need to set the `dtyoe`.  It can infer it from the `data` own dtype.

Comment: `label.astype('S1')` also works - it can save bytestrings, but not unicode (the default for PY3), at least not directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your labels are not integers, they are strings, that's a problem for HDF5. Your error message relates to an array consisting of strings of length 1. See [Strings in HDF5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html) for more details.

You can convert to integers before or after you construct your NumPy array, here are a couple of examples:

```
label = np.array(label).astype(int)
# or, label = np.array(list(map(int, label)))
```

Alternatively, since your values are `0` or `1`, choosing `bool` may be more efficient:

```
label = np.array(label).astype(int).astype(bool)
```

Also, consider holding meta-data as [attributes](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html).

Comment: thank you for your replay, I think bool is not a good type for me because I need 0 and 1 for my label. what do you mean by 'consider holding meta-data as attributes'?

Comment: For attributes, I suggest you look at [Attributes in h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html). The idea is that data sits in datasets and attributes sit in attributes. Attributes are like datasets but can be attached to a group or dataset and are always read in all at once.

Comment: thank you, I use 'label = np.array(list(map(int, label)))' before constructing numpy arrays for labels, this solved my problem, I want to feed the datasets to CNN model for training and testing, do you think I need attributes?

Comment: @honar.cs, Sorry, no idea. I have no experience with CNN model.

Comment: no problem I am very thankful for your helpful answer.

Comment: sorry but I have another question, after saving my data and labels in '.h5' file, when I try the content of two datasets inside the file, the data dataset shows a 4d array but my data was a 3d array. see image in the link: https://imgur.com/6vk7IBe

Comment: @honar.cs, I think you should ask a separate question, showing what you expect to see what you are seeing (without images).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176966/discussion-between-honar-cs-and-jpp).